# Debian 11 port listen but can't connect

Tags: postgresql, debian, timeout, port

Today I trying to connect to my remote server postgres with pgAdmin, but I get this error
"Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "XXX.XX.XXX.XX" port 5432 failed: timeout expired.
So I look inside the remote serve and I see that with

```
ss -tnlp command:
State     Recv-Q    Send-Q       Local Address:Port       Peer Address:Port    Process
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("sshd",pid=106,fd=3))
LISTEN    0         64                 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*        users:(("postgres",pid=111,fd=5))
LISTEN    0         20               127.0.0.1:25              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("exim4",pid=407,fd=4))
LISTEN    0         1                  0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*        users:(("nc",pid=477,fd=3))
LISTEN    0         128                   [::]:22                 [::]:*        users:(("sshd",pid=106,fd=4))
LISTEN    0         64                    [::]:5432               [::]:*        users:(("postgres",pid=111,fd=6))
LISTEN    0         20                   [::1]:25                 [::]:*        users:(("exim4",pid=407,fd=5))
LISTEN    0         100                      *:8080                  *:*        users:(("java",pid=606,fd=21))
LISTEN    0         511                      *:80                    *:*        users:(("node",pid=579,fd=17))
```

And my pg_hba.conf look like :

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
#IPv4 remote connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
#IPv6 remote connections:
host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5
```

So I don't understand why I can't connect to postgres.
In addition, I try with telnet on port 5432, and after long time I get that:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out.

I also try with my remote server to open port with this command:

```
nc -l -v 5555 &
```

and with other computer try with telnet/nc -zv XXX.XX.XX.XX 5555, and I get always this error

`Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out.`

And with telnet on ports 22, 8080 80 it work.

Can someone, explains me why I can't unreachable my server on port 5432 ?
Thanks
EDIT: UFW is disable

Comment: 1) What is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf`? 2) Where is the remote server located. 3) Are you sure there is not another firewall between you and it, say a cloud provider's. **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: listen_addresses is set to '*', the remote server is located in France. But following your comment is ask my host, and he told me he has a firewall before my remote server.
So I have try to change port of postgres, on 8080, and it's work. Now I will check with the provider to see if they can allow a specific port

Comment: Either that or ssh into the server and use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: Or you could set up an SSH tunnel: `ssh -N -L 54320:localhost:5432 user@remote_server` and then in `pgAdmin` use `localhost` for host and `54320` for the port.

Comment: My provider have add rule for port 5432, and now it's work. Thank a lot @AdrianKlaver, you solve my problem :)

Comment: Not sure that having your database directly open to the world is a good idea, but if you are fine with it then problem solved.